# Bounds on Expectation $E[A(B-C)^2]$

Tags: probability, expected-value, bounds

[This question has been edited for more given conditions].

Given possibly correlated random variables $A,B,C$, I want to find the best upper bound for $E[A(B-C)^2]$ given the following:

- $E[A(B-C)]$
- $Cov(A,B), Cov(A,C)$
- $E[B-C]$
- $E[A^k]$, $E[B^k]$, $E[C^k]$ for $k\geq 1$

If it helps, $A$ here is a binary random variable. I have some trivial bounds using problem specific information, but I want to see if there is a universal tight bound that I am missing here.

Comment: Absent any information about the correlation between $A$ and $B$ and between $A$ and $C$, there does not seem that much can be said.

Comment: @DilipSarwate The question is updated - is there anything that could be said now?

Comment: The more constraints you apply, the less interesting and applicable the result will get.  With infinitely many constraints, it therefore is unlikely that anyone will be inspired to work hard on this question.  Could you tell us what the problem is that you actually face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the covariance of $A$ with the higher-order moments of $B$ and $C$, which is going to limit your ability to get a tight bound.  It seems to me that the only thing you can do here is to use the fact that $A$ is binary to impose the bound $0 \leqslant A \leqslant 1$ and you then have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
0 \leqslant \mathbb{E}(A(B-C)^2) 
&\leqslant \mathbb{E}((B-C)^2) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(B^2 - 2BC + C^2) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(B^2) - 2 \mathbb{E}(BC) + \mathbb{E}(C^2) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(B^2) - 2 \mathbb{Cov}(B,C) - 2 \mathbb{E}(B)\mathbb{E}(C) + \mathbb{E}(C^2). \\[6pt]
&\leqslant \mathbb{E}(B^2) + 2 \mathbb{S}(B) \mathbb{S}(C) - 2 \mathbb{E}(B)\mathbb{E}(C) + \mathbb{E}(C^2), \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where the standard deviations $\mathbb{S}(B)$ and $\mathbb{S}(C)$ can be obtained from the moments you have given.  (For the last step, we note that you have not given sufficient information to get $\mathbb{Cov}(B,C)$, so here we have to use its largest bound in magnitude, given by the square root of the product of the variances.)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if a tighter bound could be achieved with our known first order moments, but it seems like that is not possible. The motivation of the problem is that the higher moments of B-C are nonidentifiable from data due to censorship. If no one comes with a better answer soon, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There different upper bound as you said. For one of them as $A$ is binary, we can say $S = E(A(B-C)^2) \leq p_1E((B-C)^2)$ (Because of values of $A$ is $0$ and $1$). As $p_1$ which the probability of comming $1$ and less than $1$, we can say $S \leq E((B-C)^2) = E(B^2) + E(C^2) - 2E(BC) \leq E(B^2) + E(C^2)$ if $B$ and $C$ are positive.

You can also use from [these inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) to might find some better upper bounds.